# AxesSubplot has no attribute hist2d - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a hist2d chart as one of a few subplots on a figure.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot2grid( (3,3), (0,1) )
ax.hist2d(x_data, y_data, bins=50, cmap="Greens")
plt.show()
```

I get an `AttributeError` complaining that `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'hist2d'`.  The api reference and example code online show that hist2d is an attribute of an axes.  I am able to plot surfaces and bars with my axes object, just not hist2d.  I have not had any luck on Google.  Did something go wrong with my matplotlib install?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?  `hist2d` is a relatively recent addition. (Don't remember the exact version... 1.1 maybe?)

Comment: Yeah this code works fine for me with matplotlib version 1.3.1.

Comment: I was using version 1.1.1, I upgraded to 1.3.1 and reconfigured my PYTHONPATH and now it works!  Thanks!!